# How to pass a block (which becomes a Proc object) to a ruby method

Tags: ruby, proc

I'm reading the [Pickaxe book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0974514055) on Ruby and I've come across this example:

```
class TaxCalculator
  def initialize(name, &block)
    @name, @block = name, block
  end

  def get_tax(amount)
    "#@name on #{amount} = #{@block.call(amount)}"
  end
end

tc = TaxCalculator.new ("Sales tax") {|amt| amt * 0.075 }

tc.get_tax(100) # => "Sales tax on 100 = 7.5"
tc.get_tax(250) # => "Sales tax on 250 = 18.75"
```

The point of the example is to illustrate that if you prefix the last parameter in a method definition with an ampersand, any associated block is coverted to a Proc object, and that object is assigned to the parameter.

Now, that all makes sense, but I'm stumped on one thing: why do you need to assign `name` and `block` to `@block` in the initialize method? Why do you need `name`?

To me it seems like this should work:

```
 def initialize(name, &block)
   @name, @block = block
 end
```

But, when I try that in irb `@block` becomes nil and I get an error, `NoMethodError (undefined method "call" for nil:NilClass)`.

I don't understand what `name` is doing in that `@block` assignment. It makes sense that you would want to pass "Sales Tax" to `@name`. But I don't see how "Sales Tax" is being used by the block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment syntax has nothing to do with blocks. Instead, what is happening here is called "parallel assignment".

With that, you can assign multiple variables on the left from multiple values on the right with one atomic operation. From your example, this statement

```
@name, @block = name, block
```

is equivalent to

```
@name = name
@block = block
```

In this example, this usage is more of a gimmick (which I'd flag in a code-review). However, there are some patterns where parallel assignment is very useful.

The most import one is the ability to switch the values of two variables without requiring an intermediate variable:

```
a = 1
b = 2
a, b = b, a
```

Another option is the ability to deconstruct an array into multiple variables. In the following example, the method returns an array whose elements get assigned to the two variables `hello` and `world`.

```
def get_array
  [:hello, :world]
end

hello, world = get_array
```

Comment: Ok got it. That clears it up completely. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The example is using Ruby's parallel assignment operator.

```
age, salary = 30, 3000   # age=30, salary=3000
age, salary = 30         # age=30, salary=nil
age, salary = [30, 3000] # age=30, salary=3000
```

> But I don't see how "Sales Tax" is being used by the block.

The block is not using "Sales Tax". It just computes the tax for the amount passed in `get_tax` method.